# Isolating myself and focusing on studies

Tags: interpersonal-issues, independent-study

Looking for some useful tips for focusing on studies.

Three of my semesters were held in online mode. I was at home and was totally focused. Our fourth semester started in offline mode recently. I had to move to hostel. Here I don't have any other options than to meet several people throughout the day, in classes, in canteen (having food 4 times a day). Some of them have positive impact on my mind, some are negative. I am finding it very difficult to concentrate on studies. My interactions with other students, are getting repeated on my head 24 hours a day, difficulty getting sleep also. I just went home for 2 days, and I was again able to study. And after coming back, again unable to get people out of my head.

How do I forget about other people and concentrate on my studies? It is my final semester, I really need to complete all subjects and my final year research. So any good suggestion/ tips will be helpful.

Comment: "My interactions with other students, are getting repeated on my head 24 hours a day, difficulty getting sleep also." This is not normal. I would encourage you to consult a mental health professional. Often, universities offer some kind of counseling service.

Comment: I have seen this in many people, specially when you don't have much interaction, and all of a sudden many interactions. Like you attend a ceremony, and you keep ruminating on your interaction with relatives for a few days. Seen this occasionally. In my case, that ceremony is not a single day ceremony, it's continuing. So wanted tips for concentrating on myself.

Comment: You might have to dedicate some time to get used to being around people after all that isolation. I'm afraid there's no shortcut.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**You can focus when you are alone**

As you told, you were totally focused when you were at home. Try to make a similar environment here. After the class, rush to your room, put a "Don't Disturb" sign and concentrate. Come out for classes, food and washroom only.

**Not so soft**

If you are soft to other people, somebody will get you entangled with non-study activities. Be little unfriendly and tell you are busy.

**Self study time**

Change your self study time table.

1. Go to sleep very early (around 7 p.m.).
2. Sleep for 8 hours straight. Initially you will find some difficulty
   with your friends who will try to disturb you. But be stubborn and
   don't get up. In few days every one will know about your sleeping
   time.
3. Get up at 3 a.m. and start you studies. You will be astonished how fast
   you can absorb.

You can go to sleep when you come back from classes. Sleep for 8 hours. Get up at 12:30 a.m. and study.

**This method has been tried and found very successful.**

Comment: Yes, this method might be useful. I remember, in school, mom used to make us sleep after we come back from school. Only problem is, canteen will not be open at 12:30 am. However I can work on making my own arrangement for food.

Comment: @Sukti Sen If canteen is much more important than your grades and your future life then as Roland has written in his comment "consult a mental health professional".

Comment: It has got some relation. healthy food -> increased brain power -> increased grades -> hopefully better future life (debatable). Thanks for you original answer.

Comment: @Sukti Sen One of my friends (during exams) used to buy a carton of long life milk (12 liters or more) some bread, cheese, jam, apples etc., put them in his fridge and locked the room after evening. In day time, you can go to classes, eat a lot of very healthy food, even meet your friends. My answer is only for early evening till morning. I wish for you a very high GPA and very happy future life.